# Bibliography started from the second page

Tags: bibtex

I am writing a paper using latex,the last part of the main file looks like this

```
\include{Appendix}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

In my bibfile only BibTeX cite list exits. My problem is after running the code, i will get the first page of bibliography part empty. It has only the title "Bibliography" but the references start from the 2nd page.
I dont have any problem when running, can anyone tell me what might be my problem?

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{report}
\usepackage[noadjust,verbose,sort]{cite}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without a working, compilable document, this is hard to tell.

Comment: For sure, please tell us which document class you use, as well as any packages that modify the appearance of the appendices and/or the bibliography.

Comment: the document class i used is
 \documentclass[12 pt]{report}
and the packages that may modify the bibliography is 
\usepackage[noadjust,verbose,sort]{cite}  
i am not sure if these can affect the bibliography but i have also used 
 \usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

Comment: A [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) (<- click) would be great. It is the only way we can reproduce your problem and suggest a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may come from the fact that you placed

> \bibliographystyle{plain}

After

> \bibliography{bibfile}

While it should be placed **before**.

Comment: I have tried in both ways exchanging the places the outcome is the same

Comment: It is not relevant, where the style is defined. It is written to the aux-file from where bibtex uses it.